# Add target=_blank to wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode, but I don't really know where is that defined. I just want to add `target=_blank` to the link.

Here is the shortcode:

```
[box_wide image="IMAGE LINK" text_top="Paypal" text_title="Donate our scholarship holders" text_description="Donate to our scholarship fund via Paypal. (Registration is not necessary, you can pay by card)" link="SITE HYPERLINK" text_align="left"]
```

How can I add this without finding the source and add an extra attribute? I just want to use it only in this case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try to add attribute target="_blank"?

Comment: @MainulHasan unfortunately not working :(